# Azure Concurrency Boost?

Tags: wcf, http, azure, concurrency, owin

I am trying to create a simple OWIN/Katana - hosted web service, resident in an Azure Worker Role. I expect high concurrency situations to arise,and am trying to figure out how to increase things like the HTTP.Sys queue limit and make other configuration changes that boost concurrency (like max concurrent instances in WCF).

All ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for throttling the selfhost katana. For katana selfhost you can throttle the underlying HttpListener by using the following way:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var owinHttpListener = (OwinHttpListener)app.Properties["Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener"];
            //Default for maxAccepts = 5 * ProcCount
            //Default for maxRequests = Int32.MaxValue;
            owinHttpListener.SetRequestProcessingLimits(x, y);

            //Your OWIN pipeline here...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuration changes to the machine level config values, IIS values and what not can be accomplished for both Web and Worker roles by using [start up tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx).  Specifically you should be able to use appcmd.xe to set the change for the HTTP.sys queue limit (Note, I've not tried it personally, but if you use a start up command with elevated rights I don't see why it wouldn't work).

Example (for 2008, 2012 should be similar I'd think):
appcmd.exe set config /section:serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:<#of users * 1.5>.

Docs for appcmd.exe command line: [Modifying the ASP.NET queue length limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425294%28v=office.13%29.aspx)

Note that this can be tricky depending on what you are trying to accomplish, so check out this [other MS documentation on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974418.aspx).

Comment: I didn't know appcmd.exe was available for configuring Azure settings (like that one).

Comment: It is for Web and Worker roles for start up tasks.